# can i push update to play store of my native app (while previous one build is developed on ionic)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk

I have a project ready on ionic and want to push a build to play store
but the client needs to port that project into native, and for that it takes time.
the thing is the client needs to publish the build now which developed on ionic and then pushing an update which developed native when it gets finished.

I want to know is it possible?
if yes then can you guys help me to figure out the limitation for play store console (if any*)
and any issue occurs when user update the app ionic to a native app (if any*)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Such Limitation, Make sure you have set and have following things correctly

1) The app identifier for example (com.example.app) should be the same as the original app.

2) When you build the apk file make sure, you are using the same key file which was used in publishing the app for the first time.

Hope it Helps

Comment: is any common issue from user side when user app gets updated from ionic build to native build?

Comment: No, there would not be any issue as long as you have built the apk file correctly, apart from this, if the app has login functionality, the updated users will be log out from the app, they would need to sign in again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. There are no such limitations on the Play Store Console as well. As long as the package name is the same you'll be able to update the App on the Play Store Console.

Comment: is any common issue from user side when user app gets updated from ionic build to native build?

Comment: No, and as @Amit K Khanchandani mentioned, if your app has a login functionality, the user will be logged out to add to that if your app has a local database, the data will be cleared. Make sure to ask your users to back up the data if the data is critical.